# Where to create own thread, Inside service class or Inside the activity form where we give call to the service

Tags: android, android-service

In android A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process, I want to know that if I want to create my own thread, then where to create it, Inside service class or Inside the activity form where we give call to the service ..?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity should start your service, then start your thread inside the service. If you put your service launching code in a thread, all that would do is start the thread in the background but the service (and consequently the code you want to run in the background) would still run on the Main thread

If your aren't trying do some continuously running task, I would suggest using an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). With an IntentService all most of the thread handling and the service cleanup is done for you.

Comment: thanks , 
I want to look for new JSON data in the background and notify the user if there id new JSON data fetched from url, will it be good to use IntentServece or process it inside new process..??

Comment: You can either create an IntentService that will perform the check once and then finishes it's self. The activity will have to start the IntentService everytime you want to perform the check. or you can create a regular service that ha starts a thread. The thread would then contain an infinite loop that constantly checks. In the second scenario, the activity only has to start the service once. So I guess this depends on how frequently you need to check. If it is very frequent (once every few seconds) I would go the second route. However, if is less frequent than that, do first one.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if you need your thread to persist after your activity is gone, then you need to run it in a service. The point of a service is to persist beyond the life of an activity.

Passing data across activities, services and threads may complicate the answer, and so you may end up running a thread in a service even if the thread does not persist after the activity, but that is a rare case.